# Listening to an angular animation with RxJS fromEvent

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-animations

Im trying to listen to `@animation.done` event of an angular animation.
I used `@HostListener`

```
@HostListener('@animation.done', ['$event'])
    onAnimationDone(): void {
     console.log('Animation Done);
    }
```

and it was warking fine but now I would like to use `fromeEvent` from RxJS. I tried:

```
fromEvent(this.hostElementRef.nativeElement, '@animation.done')
            .pipe(tap(() => console.log('animation end')))
            .subscribe();
```

Sadly, nothing happens.
Animation is applied with `@HostBinding`:

```
@HostBinding('@animation') animated = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HostBinding` and `HostListener` can use both regular events and what's referred t by angular in the code as a "synthetic host property" (in our case a "synthetic host event"). [These](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/327896606832bf6fbfc8f23989755123028136a8/packages/core/src/render3/instructions/host_property.ts) seem to be using metadata and are not actually bound to the host.

Therefore `fromEvent`, which relies solely on DOM events, cannot detect these.

When you dig into the animations' package code you find that listening relies on the [listenOnPlayer](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/327896606832bf6fbfc8f23989755123028136a8/packages/animations/browser/src/render/shared.ts#L73) function which uses the [AnimationPlayer](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/327896606832bf6fbfc8f23989755123028136a8/packages/animations/src/players/animation_player.ts#L22)'s methods which, if you look at the [NoopAnimationPlayer](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/327896606832bf6fbfc8f23989755123028136a8/packages/animations/src/players/animation_player.ts#L121) implementation, are just backed by an array of listeners.

Therefore, there's no way to use `fromEvent` with them. And from what I've seen, the animations' package doesn't provide any rxjs interop or entry point.